# Using fgetcsv() to generate HTML table with row data-attributes from array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I'm using `fgetcsv()` to read a csv file of this format...

```
Make, Model, Origin, Color, Miles, Options
Chevy, Tahoe, Delaware, Black, 10000, LX
Ford, F150, Texas, Red, 5000, S
Chevy, Corvette, Utah, Red, 12000, SE
Mazda, Miata, Florida, Blue, 90000, LX
```

...and then generate an HTML table. Although I can get each data value into an individual cell, I'd like to list the model's `color` and `options` values as HTML data-attributes. **So my current output looks like this**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Chevy</td>
        <td>Tahoe</td>
        <td>Delaware</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>LX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Ford</td>
        <td>F150</td>
        <td>Texas</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td>S</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**When I'd like it to look like this**:

```
<table>
    <tr data-color="black" data-options="LX">
        <td>Chevy</td>
        <td>Tahoe</td>
        <td>Delaware</td>
        <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-color="red" data-options="s">
       <td>Ford</td>
        <td>F150</td>
        <td>Texas</td>
        <td>5000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, the PHP I'm using now just supplies the data-attribute value of "color" (from the labels row) as the attribute on every `<tr>`. For example,

```
    <tr data-color="Color" data-options="Options">
       <td>Ford</td>
        <td>F150</td>
        <td>Texas</td>
        <td>5000</td>
    </tr>
```

Does anyone have recommendations to get the appropriate value from the array as the data-attribute for each row? Here's my current PHP:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("cars.csv", "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    $color = $data[3];
    $options = $data[5];
    echo('<table>');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr data-color="' . $color . '" data-options="' . $options . '">');
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');
        }
        echo('</tr>');
    }
    echo("</table>");
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: You are setting `$color` outside of your loop, but never updating the value inside the loop. You could probably just change `$color` to `$data[3]` inside the loop and you would be fine.

Comment: Sure enough, that fixed it...thanks for the input. If you add as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting $color outside of your loop, but never updating the value inside the loop. You could probably just change $color to $data[3] inside the loop and you would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

your `$color` and `$options` variables are currently just the column headers.

Change you code to something like this:

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("cars.csv", "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    $color = $data[3];
    $options = $data[5];
    echo('<table>');
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $color = $data[3];
        $options = $data[5];
        //generate HTML
        echo('<tr data-color="' . $color . '" data-options="' . $options . '">');
        foreach ($data as $index=>$val) {
            echo('<td>');
            echo htmlentities($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            echo('</td>');
        }
        echo('</tr>');
    }
    echo("</table>");
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: Scott thanks for the answer - I upvoted but saw Jonathan's first, so I've accepted his